# Why does count() overwrite a value?

Tags: php, arrays, count

Today I ran into some php behaviour which puzzles me.

Let's consider the following code:

```
$arr = [11, 22];
echo json_encode($arr);  // prints [11,22] as expected
$result = count($arr =! 0);
echo json_encode($arr);  // prints true
```

I know the usage of count is wrong in the sense that I feed it a boolean instead of an array which it expects.

BUT

Why oh why does the wrong usage of count overwrite the value of a part of the array??

Comment: `count($arr =! 0);` is equivalent to `$arr = !0;` (at this stage, `$arr` is _"not zero"_, ie `true`) then `$result = count($arr);` happens which will probably throw an error in PHP 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per PHP Comparison operators we should do Not equal to as **!=** but it shouldn't be like **=!**

```
$arr = [11, 22];
echo json_encode($arr);  // prints [11,22] as expected
$result = count($arr != 0);
echo json_encode($arr);  // prints [11,22] as expected
```

run the above code snippet. it gives result as expected

Comment: Yes, that was the mistake! I took and simplified this code from some production machine and just didn't see why it behaved like this. Thanks!

Comment: You can't count a boolean. This will throw an error in PHP 7

Answer (score 0):

count() is a php array based function, it expects array as a parameter and returns the count of elements in it, so it can't be used to make any kind of check, which you are doing in your 3rd line.

Answer (score -1):

Because false is also a value and if the count() does not get array but a valid variable it returns true which is 1 . A nice way to remember this in your mind: count(false) is basically the same as: count ("one boolean"), and therefore there are "ONE" booleans as result.